# Highlighting Lines in ListBox with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox that will display text normally but when an error occurs, only the first line will be reverse video, the remainder will be normal text.  I can display lines normally but can't reverse video a line from the program.  I did it using Windows Forms but I am upgrading to WPF.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In the .xaml file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="_ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="_Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

On the List Box:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="528" Margin="25,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1351" Background="#FFDDDDDD" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}"/>
```

In the .cs code:

```
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MainWindow mv = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            _ = mv.TestList.Items.Add(str);
            mv.TestList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }));
```